# Android: How do you know when your app is seachable and shown in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app 6 hours ago. I can view it in the Google Play store from my dev cobsole. However if I search for it in Google Play I cannot find it.

How do I know the status of it? 
Is there some notification when it is shown in the Play store?
Annoying if I have to search for it to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take a Day or Two to become searchable for all users.
Now you can share your app with your friends through the URL of your app in social spaces.
I had the same concern when i publish my app. 
Hope Google will look in to this soon.